# Ajax and PHP Get wont send data to server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have a problem, I need to send data to server, I'm using ajax for sending data. I tested everything on my test-server and all worked. But when I tryed to do it in my server.. It sometimes work, and most of the time just giving me gray 200 OK network status, I cant figure out why.. Here some pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the transfer column when you open the network, you are getting a notice that your request's response has been cached,

I think this is explained here :

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53942/why-is-this-response-being-cached

To avoid caching you have to send the following values in the header request:

`headers: {
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 
     'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
     'Expires': '0'
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Grey in Firefox means that the document was put in cache, and was retreived from cache rather than getting the file (you can see it on a column on the right).

It is still 200, which means it's allright for you.. (unless you don't, then you have to disable the caching)

Answer (score 0):

may be you have not mentioned the dataType in ajax call, please provide sample code of ajax you have write so we can find error.